# How to upload file into Wasabi bucket with s3 api with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, wasabi-hot-cloud-storage

I implemented uploading file in Amazon s3 bucket like below and it works fine:

```
  const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');
  const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

  const accessKeyId = 'AKIAYVXDX*******';
  const secretAccessKey = 'gxZpdSDnOfpM*****************';

  const s3 = new S3({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey
  });

  s3.putObject({
      Body: 'Hello World',
      Bucket: "dev-amazon",
      Key: 'hello.txt'
    }
    , (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
         console.log(err);
      }
    });
```

And I need to implement uploading file in Wasabi bucket.

I tried like below:

```
  const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');
  const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  const wasabiEndpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('s3.wasabisys.com');

  const accessKeyId = 'PEIL4DYOY*******';
  const secretAccessKey = 'D4jIz3tjJw*****************';

  const s3 = new S3({
    endpoint: wasabiEndpoint,
    region: 'us-east-2',
    accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey
  });

  s3.putObject({
      Body: 'Hello World',
      Bucket: "dev-wasabi",
      Key: 'hello.txt'
    }
    , (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
         console.log(err);
      }
    });
```

And the result of `console.log(err) is:

> err {"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.","code":"SignatureDoesNotMatch","region":null,"time":"2019-10-30T09:39:19.072Z","requestId":null,"statusCode":403,"retryable":false,"retryDelay":64.72166771381391}

Console error in devtools:

> PUT https://dev-wasabi.s3.us-east-2.wasabisys.com/5efa9b286821fab7df3ece8dc3d6687ed32 403 (Forbidden)

What is wrong in my codes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After some research, I found that `wasabiEndpoint` was wrong.

It should be

```
const wasabiEndpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('s3.us-east-2.wasabisys.com ');
```

According to [docs](https://wasabi-support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015106031-What-are-the-service-URLs-for-Wasabi-s-different-regions-), service URLs should be different based on regions.

> Wasabi US East 1 (N. Virginia): s3.wasabisys.com or s3.us-east-1.wasabisys.com
>
> Wasabi US East 2 (N. Virginia): s3.us-east-2.wasabisys.com
>
> Wasabi US West 1 (Oregon): s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com
>
> Wasabi EU Central 1 (Amsterdam): s3.eu-central-1.wasabisys.com

Will be more than happy if this can help someone. ;)

Comment: I'm following these instructions to the point and i'm getting an error:
code: 'InvalidARN',  message: 'ARN region is empty'. Don't find any docs on it

Answer (score 0):

When using the [@aws-sdk/client-s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html) package, the S3 client only needs the Wasabi endpoint defined. The following will create the S3 client w/ the correct endpoint:

```js
const client = new S3Client({
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: "<wasabi-access-key-id>",
        secretAccessKey: "<wasabi-secret-key>"
    },
    endpoint: {
        url: "https://s3.wasabisys.com"
    }
})
```

From here, putting an object is exactly the same as a standard AWS S3 bucket. Ex:

```js
await client.send(new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: "bucket-name",
    Key: "object-key",
    Body: <whatever is being put>
})
```

With the basic import statement being:

```js
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3"
```

Comment: Region is missing